# Javascript function not displaying within HTML form element

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

[image: Form Execution Log]
[image: HTML Form Snippet]

I have a javascript function which writes an input element into a HTML form based on a search through a google sheet.

I give it a search criteria based upon a dropdown within the form. The input element isn't displaying when I use the 'result' variable, I can see through the logs that the input element is being created with the correct parameters.

If I replace that variable with a value "18000", which is an option in the dropdown, the input element displays.

Can't see as to why it wouldn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT
Below is my javascript file.

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

/**
 * Handles HTTP GET requests to the published web app.
 * @return {HtmlOutput} The HTML page to be served.
 */
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function doGet(){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
      
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
  
}

//Formatting
function formatting(){
  var fms = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10jSs0uoHOgO9VZusCa0ApyXmqISsHqsubIfRXiRPcQg');
  var ms = fms.getSheetByName('Update Projects');
  var column = ms.getRange("B2:B");
  column.setNumberFormat("@");
}

function getJobs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10jSs0uoHOgO9VZusCa0ApyXmqISsHqsubIfRXiRPcQg');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Projects Progress");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow); 
  var data    = myRange.getValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=1) {
    optionsHTML += '<option value =' + data[i][0] + '>' + data[i][0] + '</option>';
  };
  return optionsHTML;
}

function projectData(result) {

  result = result || "sample";  // Added
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10jSs0uoHOgO9VZusCa0ApyXmqISsHqsubIfRXiRPcQg');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Projects Progress");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var search = result;
var optionsHTML = ""
if (!result) {  // Added
  return sheet.getRange(1, 3, sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().reduce((s, [NICEIC]) => s += '<input id="mytext" name="NICEIC" type="text" placeholder="NICEIC" value="' + NICEIC + '" tabindex="2">', "");
}
Logger.log(search);
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][0] == search){ 
    var NICEIC = sheet.getRange((i+1), 3).getDisplayValue();
    var ComissSheets = sheet.getRange((i+1), 4).getDisplayValue();
    Logger.log(NICEIC); 
    Logger.log(ComissSheets); 
     optionsHTML += '<fieldset> <h4>NICEIC Testing and Draft Certs</h4> <input id="mytext" name="NICEIC" type="text" placeholder="NICEIC" value="' + NICEIC + '" tabindex="2"> </fieldset>';
    }
  }; 
  Logger.log(optionsHTML );
  return NICOptionsHTML;
}
```

EDIT:
Below is my HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/formdata-polyfill"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/promise-polyfill@latest"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/whatwg-fetch@latest"></script>

<script>
  const scriptURL = '<SCRIPT URL>'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
  ...
</script>
<script>
function getChoice(){
  var formObject = document.getElementById("projectNoView");
  var result = formObject.options[formObject.selectedIndex].text;
        google.script.run.projectData(result);
        Logger.log(result);
}
</script>
  </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post" name="submit-to-google-sheet">
    <h3>Update Projects Progress Form</h3>
    <fieldset>
    <br>
    <h4>Project Number</h4>
      <select id="projectNoView" name="jobNumber"type="number" placeholder="Project No." onchange="getChoice()" tabindex="1" required >
      <?!= getJobs(); ?>
      </select>
    </fieldset> 
     <fieldset>
    <h4>NICEIC Testing and Draft Certs</h4>    
      <?!= projectData(); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" onclick="formReset()">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>


<script>
const allRanges = document.querySelectorAll(".range-wrap");
allRanges.forEach(wrap => {
  const range = wrap.querySelector(".range");
  const bubble = wrap.querySelector(".bubble");

  range.addEventListener("input", () => {
    setBubble(range, bubble);
  });
  setBubble(range, bubble);
});

function setBubble(range, bubble) {
  const val = range.value;
  const min = range.min ? range.min : 0;
  const max = range.max ? range.max : 100;
  const newVal = Number(((val - min) * 100) / (max - min));
  bubble.innerHTML = val;

  // Sorta magic numbers based on size of the native UI thumb
  bubble.style.left = `calc(${newVal}% + (${8 - newVal * 0.15}px))`;
}
</script>

<script>
function updateTextInput(val) {
          document.getElementById('slider').value=val; 
        }
</script>

<script>
  const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzYR6JvRhjrv_ia9itggnjuy7Qfn7e2PrNiDn7QJCRmk6bhR3pq/exec'
  const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']

  form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
      .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  })
</script>







<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #777;
  background: #add8e6 ;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="number"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact select,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="number"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact select {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="number"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #013d83;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #00adfe;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

.range-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 3rem;
}
.range {
  width: 100%;
}
.bubble {
  background: #add8e6;
  color: black;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.bubble::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #add8e6;
  top: -1px;
  left: 50%;
}

/* Buttons styles start */
button {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #0069ed;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
    background: #0053ba;
}

button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid #fff;
    outline-offset: -4px;
}

</style>


  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Below is a shared sheet which is similar to the data I am trying to pull from.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DTmqQK-l9icyMryEtOVqfQihbDjFDHXaf4P9NW2MDS0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The code is incomplete. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Did you want me to post the whole of my code? As they are the relevant parts.

Comment: Not the whole code, just the minimal code required to reproduce the problem. By the way, the code of current revision of question includes two declarations of `doGet` there should be only one.

Comment: @Josh Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when I saw it, I noticed that my comment was not reflected. 1. At your added script, in HTML, I cannot find `<fieldset><h4>NICEIC Testing and Draft Certs</h4><?!= projectData(); ?></fieldset>` in your initial question. 2. there are 2 `doGet()`. I think that by my poor English skill, you misunderstood my comment. I apologize for this. So in the current stage, I would like to delete my answer. Because my answer was not suitable for your current question. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: No worries, sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the help. Do you think it could be a data type error?

Comment: Are you getting any error on the console? and is ```result``` any option in your dropdown menu?

Comment: Not getting any error. Yeah thats correct result is anything that the user selects in the dropdown. I can see the data in the execution log in the correct format, just not displaying in the form.

Comment: Interesting, could you please share a sample spreadsheet or an image showing how data is being displayed in the sheet so that I can try to reproduce as accuratelly as possible your issue?

Comment: I have added a shared sheet, which is the same as the sheet I am trying to pull the data from.

Comment: Hi ! So after reviewing further your code I have some suggestions for your for troubleshooting : 1.  **Move the ```script``` code where you call ```getChoice()``` below the form ```HTML``` code** (right now I think it is being executed before the actual form itself. 2. In ```projectData()``` you are returning a variable that does not exist, change that for whatever you really want to return. 3. Remove one of the ```doGet``` as they are repeated functions. Let me know if any of these options helped you fix or improve the state of your current situation :D

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, What do you mean by point 2? As the result variable is what I want to return as that is the value of the dropdown.

Comment: You are returning ```NICOptionsHTML``` which I dont see referenced before

Comment: Ah I see, sorry syntax mistake. With those corrections, it is still the same. I have added an image in the question of the execution log, to show that the variables are being pulled from the data correctly just not displaying on the form.

Comment: I think your main problem is that when you call the ```projectData()``` function in the HTML part you are not passing any values into the function when this function is **actually expecting an input parameter**. To see if this is the main error, please modify and use the following instead ```<?!= projectData(80); ?>``` and let me know if passing an parameter in that ```HTML``` item solves the issue.